# Chat: Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURLs'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to implement a chat to firebase but get this error: **Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURLs'** from this code:

```
var fileUrl: String!

func CreateNewRoom(user: User, caption: String, data: NSData) {
    let filePath = "\(user.uid)/\(Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))"
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    storageRef.child(filePath).putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error uploading: \(error as NSError)")
            return
        }
        self.fileUrl = metadata!.downloadURLs![0].absoluteString
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            let idRoom = self.BASE_REF.child("rooms").childByAutoId()
            idRoom.setValue(["caption": caption, "thumbnailUrlFromStorage": self.storageRef.child(metadata!.path!).description, "fileUrl": self.fileUrl])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StorageMetadata doesn't have a property called downloadURLs, as you can seem from the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata).  That's been deprecated a long time ago and removed from the API.  You're probably looking at an old example or tutorial.

If you need to [generate a download URL for a file in Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url), use [downloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#downloadurlcompletion) to fetch one.